# Google API Provider for movie and tv show

Tags: api, search, movie

I looked everywhere and I couldn't find what I'm looking for, I would like to develop for me a small app that based on a movie or tv show name, that tell me where I can see it for free/paid whatever.

Exactly like this:

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wr87.png)

Does anybody knows where to look for in the Google API documentation ? Thanks